# Preventing race condition when user executes multiple graphql mutations in a row

Tags: node.js, mongoose, graphql

I have async GraphQL mutation, which does the following:

1. finds photo by id, and removes it from db (mongoDB, using mongoose).
2. finds user by id, removes photo from users list of photos, and then saves the user.

So I have one db for photos, and one for users. All photos are separate documents in photos-db, and photo-id's are also saved to user-db.

Problem is, that if I run this many times quickly, it does remove photos from photo-db, but failed to remove photo-id's from user-db. It removes first photo-id, but subsequent photo-id's are not removed.

Code below:

```
deletePhoto: async (_root: undefined, args: { id: string }, context: UserInContext): Promise<Photo | null> => {
    const currentUser = context.currentUser;
    const id = args.id;
    const isOwnPhoto = currentUser.photos.includes(id);

    console.log('user', currentUser.id);

    if (!currentUser || (!currentUser.isAdmin && !isOwnPhoto)) {
        throw new AuthenticationError('Not authenticated');
    }

    const photo = await PhotoModel.findByIdAndDelete(args.id);
    const user = await UserModel.findById(currentUser.id);

    if (user) {
        console.log('photo removed, id:', id);
        user.photos = user.photos.filter(item => item != id);

        try {
            await user.save();
            console.log('user saved');
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('error', error.message);
        }
    }

    return photo;
}
```

Output of trying to remove 5 photos:

```
user 5f058ca0bf08318028019059
user 5f058ca0bf08318028019059
user 5f058ca0bf08318028019059
user 5f058ca0bf08318028019059
user 5f058ca0bf08318028019059
photo removed, id: 5f3cf6fdbe09d26e70efcd95
photo removed, id: 5f3cf700be09d26e70efcd96
photo removed, id: 5f3cf705be09d26e70efcd97
photo removed, id: 5f3cf709be09d26e70efcd98
photo removed, id: 5f3cf70cbe09d26e70efcd99
user saved
error No matching document found for id "5f058ca0bf08318028019059" version 116 modifiedPaths "photos"
error No matching document found for id "5f058ca0bf08318028019059" version 116 modifiedPaths "photos"
error No matching document found for id "5f058ca0bf08318028019059" version 116 modifiedPaths "photos"
error No matching document found for id "5f058ca0bf08318028019059" version 116 modifiedPaths "photos"
```

GraphQL schema below:

```
type User {
    username: String!
    password: String!
    email: String!
    fullname: String!
    isAdmin: Boolean!
    photos: [Photo!]
    id: ID!
}
  
type Photo {
    mainUrl: String!
    thumbUrl: String!
    filename: String!
    thumbFilename: String!
    originalFilename: String!
    name: String!
    description: String
    dateAdded: String
    user: User!
    id: ID!
}
  
type Mutation {
    deletePhoto(id: ID!): Photo
}
```

So user is updated one time, but 4 following updates failed. How can I prevent this happening?

Comment: What's the query and/or relevant part of the schema look like?

Comment: iterate over `user.photos`, remove if file not exists, then save user

Comment: The problem is not with GraphQL, your resolver needs to manage this with some transaction or lock

Comment: no lock needed, just not saving user.photos containing removed ids - mongo tries to link them with matching (possibly removed) document ... filter `user.photos` using `PhotoModel.exists()`, even no need to filter  out current id

Comment: Ok now I see the problem here! But can you help my how to use `exists()`? I tried: `user.photos = user.photos.filter(item => PhotoModel.exists({ id: item }));` - no errors occurred, but it does not filter out any photos anymore, `user.photos` contains all deleted photo-id's.

Comment: await? promise.all? probably it won't be one-liner ;)

Comment: I just don't know how to use async functions inside of filter...

Comment: Also, can you explain why I don't get any error when I save `user` without filtering anything out? Without filtering there are many id's that does not exists anymore, but when I save same document with some id's filtered out, I get that error `No matching document found...`?

Comment: don't do it on filter ... prepare an existingArray=promise.all of async exists() tests (returns id if exists, null otherwise), in next step filter nulls? ... search for 'how to delete in mongoose using promise.all' .... why not error? not touched property, not revalidated? ask mongo experts

Comment: What I tested and read, it seems that `exists()` return only true of false, so array of those is pretty useless for this case. I also tried to use session and wrap all mongoose actions inside of transaction, but I still get same version error..

Comment: hello .... `return true` or `false` allows to `return id` or `null` ... read about promises, resolve, promise.all etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for me was this. I'm updating `UserModel` with function `findByIdAndUpdate` using `$pullAll` operator, as it guarantees that object is not modified between fetching it and saving it.

```
deletePhoto: async (_root: undefined, args: { id: string }, context: UserInContext): Promise<Photo | null> => {
    const currentUser = context.currentUser;
    const id = args.id;
    const isOwnPhoto = currentUser.photos.includes(id);

    if (!currentUser || (!currentUser.isAdmin && !isOwnPhoto)) {
        throw new AuthenticationError('Not authenticated');
    }

    const photo = await PhotoModel.findByIdAndDelete(args.id);
    await UserModel.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: currentUser.id }, { $pullAll: { photos: [id] } });

    return photo;
}
```